# how to create aws lambda trigger in terraform?

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform

Can anyone reference or show me an example on how to create a AWS Lambda trigger with Terraform?

In the AWS console, after clicking a function name and selecting the configuration tab, you can create triggers E.g. a SNS trigger

Comment: Its trigger specific. For sns you create `aws_sns_topic_subscription`.

Answer (score 15):

For sns you need to create sns subscription

```
resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "user_updates_lampda_target" {
  topic_arn = “sns topic arn”
  protocol  = "lambda"
  endpoint  = “lambda arn here”
}
```

To allows Lambda functions to get events from Kinesis, DynamoDB and SQS you can use event source mapping

```
resource "aws_lambda_event_source_mapping" "example" {
  event_source_arn  = aws_dynamodb_table.example.stream_arn
  function_name     = aws_lambda_function.example.arn
  starting_position = "LATEST"
}
```

Answer (score 14):

For an SNS trigger it is also necessary to add a resource-based policy for the lambda to allow it to be executed by the SNS subscription.

When creating the trigger from the AWS Console this is done automatically. When using Terraform this requires adding an aws_lambda_permission:

```
resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "my_sns_subscription" {
  topic_arn = aws_sns_topic.my_sns_topic.arn
  protocol  = "lambda"
  endpoint  = aws_lambda_function.my_lambda_function.arn
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "with_sns" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromSNS"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.my_lambda_function.function_name
  principal     = "sns.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = aws_sns_topic.my_sns_topic.arn
}
```

Comment: it should be most voted